# How to refresh/redraw/reload a UIGraphicsImageRenderer in iOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uiview

I have a custom `UIView` class that draws some lines with `UIGraphicsImageRenderer`, and I have some sliders to change the points used to draw the lines, but doing so doesn't erase the old lines, it just draws new ones on top of them. I've tried adding `self.setNeedsDisplay()` near the top & bottom of the method, neither made any difference.

I got the basic idea of how to use `UIGraphicsImageRenderer` from the hackingwithswift [project 27](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/27/overview)—in that project he uses a switch statement to call different functions to draw different things, and that seems to clear & redraw things fine.

I also tried `var clearsContextBeforeDrawing: Bool = true`, but I don't think I'm using it right, I found it in the documentation.

I also saw in the `setNeedsDisplay` documentation it says "You should use this method to request that a view be redrawn only when the content or appearance of the view change. If you simply change the geometry of the view, the view is typically not redrawn"—I'm guessing by "geometry of the view" they mean things like transformations (scaling/translating/rotating)?

```
func drawLines(pointList: [CGPoint],
               cycle: Bool = false,
               lineColor: CGColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor,
               fillColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor) {

//        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 728, height: 984))
//        var clearsContextBeforeDrawing: Bool = true
    let img = renderer.image { ctx in
        ctx.cgContext.move(to: pointList[0])

        for v in pointList.dropFirst() {
            ctx.cgContext.addLine(to: v)
        }

        ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(lineColor)
        ctx.cgContext.strokePath()
    }

    let iv = UIImageView(image:img)
    iv.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    self.addSubview(iv)
//        self.setNeedsDisplay()
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding a new `UIImageView` each time you call `drawLines()`. The way your code is written, each image view has a clear background... so you are seeing your "lines" layered on top of each other.

You should have *one* `UIImageView` already added to `self` (we'll call it `theDrawingImageView`), and then change your function to end with:

```
    //let iv = UIImageView(image:img)
    //iv.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    //self.addSubview(iv)

    theDrawingImageView.image = img
}
```

**Edit:** Here is a complete demonstration. You can run this directly in a playground page.

It creates a view controller and adds a `UIButton` and a `UIImageView`. Each time you tap the button, a set of 12 random points will be generated and used to draw lines on a new `UIImage` which is then used to set the `.image` property of the image view.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class TestViewController : UIViewController {


    let theDrawingImageView: UIImageView = {
        let v = UIImageView()
        v.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()

    let btn: UIButton = {
        let b = UIButton()
        b.setTitle("Tap to Draw Lines", for: .normal)
        b.backgroundColor = .red
        b.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return b
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.25, green: 0.5, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0)

        // add button and image view to self.view
        self.view.addSubview(btn)
        self.view.addSubview(theDrawingImageView)

        // button position
        btn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // image view position
        theDrawingImageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        theDrawingImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0).isActive = true

        // image view width and height
        theDrawingImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0).isActive = true
        theDrawingImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0).isActive = true

        // add a target for the button tap
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)

    }

    // simple random number function
    func random(_ range:Range<Int>) -> Int {
        return range.lowerBound + Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(range.upperBound - range.lowerBound)))
    }

    func btnTapped(_ sender: Any) {

        var pts = [CGPoint]()

        let maxX = Int(theDrawingImageView.bounds.size.width)
        let maxY = Int(theDrawingImageView.bounds.size.height)

        // generate a set of 12 random points
        for _ in 1...12 {
            let x = random(0..<maxX)
            let y = random(0..<maxY)
            let pt = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
            pts.append(pt)
        }

        drawLines(imageView: theDrawingImageView, pointList: pts)

    }

    func drawLines(imageView: UIImageView,
                   pointList: [CGPoint],
                   cycle: Bool = false,
                   lineColor: CGColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor,
                   fillColor: CGColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor) {

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: imageView.bounds.size)

        // this creates a new UIImage and draws lines on it
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in

            ctx.cgContext.move(to: pointList[0])

            for v in pointList.dropFirst() {
                ctx.cgContext.addLine(to: v)
            }

            ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(lineColor)
            ctx.cgContext.strokePath()

        }

        // set the image view's .image to the new image with the lines drawn on it
        imageView.image = img
    }

}

let vc = TestViewController()
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = vc
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't responded or accepted your answer yet—I still haven't managed to get it working. I understand what you said about how I was creating a new `UIImageView` with each call, but I can't seem to figure out exactly how to initialize `theDrawingImageView`. I declare it with `public var theDrawingImageView: UIImageView`, and then try adding things like `init(image: UIImageView?) { self.theDrawingImageView = image super.init(image: theDrawingImageView)` I get various errors (no overload available in this case). It seems pretty clear that I don't understand what I'm doing.

Comment: @Cody - I edited my answer with a complete example that you can run in a playground page. Hopefully that will make it more clear.

Comment: I got the playground working so I think I should be able to make sense of it! Maybe because I updated to Xcode 9 recently but it had me add a `@objc` before the `btnTapped` method. Thank you!